# How to draw UIButton with tint color like UIToolbar

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, ios

I want to customize my button like those UIBarButtonItems on a UIToolbar with tint color. Does any one know how to draw that tint effect?

Comment: Do you really want them to have another color than the UIToolbar?

Comment: No, I don't use them directly on UIToolbar. I just standalone UIButtons like those UIBarButtonItems on UIToobar or UINavigationBar.

Answer (score 0):

I went nuts trying to figure this out once.

The best I could do was to do my own "custom" button, and use it as the button's "image".

The real hard part was getting the font right. The web said it was supposed to be "Helvetica" I believe - but it never looked right.

Comment: So you draw pictures with drawing tools like Photoshop and then set it to button's image? That's not what I want. What I want is a button with a tintColor property that can be set to whatever color, just like UIToolbar or UISegmentedControl.

Comment: The font is Helvetica Neue Bold

Answer (score -1):

The thing you're trying to do isn't supported.  You should just make your own button that looks the way you want it to and set it as the customView of the button item object.

Comment: I know it is not naively offered by iOS. Specifically, I want someone to give some hint for the tint algorithm that can best mimic the visual effect of UIBarButtonItems on a UIToolbar.